# link text (note) with mass property in Solidworks for different configurations

Tags: solidworks

I have a SolidWorks assembly with 2 configurations. I want to display the mass of each configuration in the model itself as a note (text). An illustration is shown in the figure below.

[image]

I have two doubts as follows:

1. I want to know if it is possible to link the note with the mass property so that when I switch over to next configuration, the note automatically updates with the new mass of the 2nd configuration.
2. Is it possible to indicate the mass of only a sub-assembly in the note.